# Can Webhooks pass user inputted values to a PHP script after a PayPal transaction?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, webhooks

I've been reading on their Instant Payment Notification, but it seems very much overkill for my simple request. I'm wondering if their newer Webhooks is an option, but I'm not understanding [their documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/) on it.

There's also a huge lack of any sort of PayPal Webhook examples or tutorials other than PayPal's documentation. If Webhooks is an option to send a user inputted value to a PHP script on my server after they've completed their PayPal transaction, how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom variable

```
<input name="custom" value="some custom value" type="hidden">
```

*Custom* Variable is given as:

> Optional pass-through variable that will never be presented to your
>   customer. Can be used to track inventory.

This variable is returned in the callback after the transaction.

You can find sample working forms and variables here: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside

Comment: Does this require the use of their IPN?

Comment: @Aaron It depends on you. If you use the variable `notify_url` in the html form then it will send a notification. But if you don't want to use IPN, then don't add the `notify_url` in your form. The first form example (in the link provided in my answer above) has no `notify_url`. IPN(Instant Payment Notification) sends a notification to your server when a payment is made/failed/cancelled/on hold..etc. This page explains the concept of IPN and handshake more clearly. [link](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/getting-started-with-paypal-ipn-and-php)